# Image Compression in android

Tags: android-camera

I'm using `PNG` format but still m getting very bad image quality..

these is my code for compression :

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
        byteArray = blob.toByteArray();
```

after these compression m writing my `byteArray` on `SDCard` but image Quality is so bad.

Answer (score 1):

below code give better image after compression, its worked for me.

```
            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
```